# AppleScript repeats; Why is there such a difference in time to run?

Tags: applescript, time-complexity

I'm trying to understand why the following AppleScript handlers complete in such different amounts of time. I have started (!) reading a little about Big O and complexity, but am struggling to apply my thus far limited understanding to these cases:

- Handler 1:

  ```
  on ranger1(n)
      set outList to {}
      repeat with i from 1 to n
          set end of outList to i
      end repeat
      return outList
  end ranger1
  ```
- Handler 2:

  ```
  on ranger2(n)
      set outList to {}
      set i to 1
      repeat n times
          set end of outList to i
          set i to i+1
      end repeat
      return outList
  end ranger2
  ```

I've tried these handlers out with values for n of up to 1 000 000. (*If anyone reading plans on trying these out, stick to values <= **100 000**!*)

Timing a call of `ranger1(100000)`:

```
set timeStart to (time of (current date))
ranger1(100000)
log (time of (current date)) - timeStart
```

is giving me a time of between 8-10 secs to complete.

However, timing a call of `ranger2(100000)` results in about 240 secs to complete.

I'm assuming that in `ranger2()` it is the statement `set i to i+1` that is increasing the "complexity" of the handler. I might be wrong, I might be right; I honestly don't know.

So, I guess my question is (!) - Am i wrong?

I will be extremely appreciative of any explanation that can help me understand the real difference between these handlers. Particularly one that can help me move towards applying concepts of "complexity" to such simple functions.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Big O tells you how the run time will develop, as the size of the data increases.
So it is really nothing practical in it, except that, a rules of thumb.

Your findings suggests that it is a little bit faster to use the repeat with i from 1 to n loop, since the counter is then increased behind the scenes. If you try to measure stuff theoretically, then the i+1 of course also counts as an extra statement. :)

Comment: Big-O rates the efficiency of an algorithm: `O(1)` constant time, `O(log n)` logarithmic time, `O(n)` linear time, `O(n*n)` quadratic time, etc. Now, on paper, you'd be right: both of the OP's algorithms _should_ have the same efficiency. However, when you actually run them for a range of `n` values (100, 1000, 10000, 100000), the first is roughly linear[1] as expected but the second is _quadratic_ (0.0003, 0.02, 2.1, 210s)! So the OP is right in identifying a performance problem, though it's not the `set` operation that's directly responsible, but some crap algorithm in the AS interpreter[2].

Comment: [1] It's actually worse than linear because AppleScript uses a really crap algorithm to grow an existing array. Basically, it allocates N bytes of memory, and when that fills up it allocates N+M bytes (where M is a fixed number) and copies the existing array data across, meaning performance degrades markedly as size increases as each M items added means another copy must be made. (Good languages allocate [e.g.] N+N bytes, doubling the memory each time, so the frequency of copying rapidly decreases as the array grows, effectively making it an ameliorated constant which can be ignored.)

Comment: [2] Not sure exactly what the performance killer is, but it's triggered as soon as you make _any_ sort of variable assignment, e.g. `set foo to ""` causes efficiency to crater just as effectively as `set i to i+1`. TBH there isn't much point speculating further: the AS interpreter has _always_ been a POS riddled with inefficient algorithms and undocumented behaviors, and that won't ever change. The _only_ thing AS is good for is application automation (and only 'cos Apple's totally bolloxed Apple event support for every other language), but for anything else use another language.

Comment: Measuring, and taking fractions, to see the development, is of course the right way, to figure out what big Oh a handler is proportional to, especially with Applescript. Doubling the size of a buffer, is also reasonable in most cases, at least as long as it is less than a megabyte. I disagree to what AppleScript is good for. It all depends, I play with algorithms and stuff with AppleScript, it is also very good for doing calculations and computations. :)

Comment: @foo: so is there an implication that `repeat from i to n` allocates more initial memory space than `repeat n times`? Is there a way for me to check the byte sizes of the arrays?

Comment: @McUsr: I do understand that allocating `i + 1` to `i` *counts as an extra statement*. I just wasn't expecting that extra statement to take the behaviour from roughly linear to roughly quadratic. Should I have? Anyway, I'll definitely be using the `repeat from to` construct wherever I can in my scripts :)

Comment: Repeat n times, obviously has its uses, but the behaviour of an assignment with respect to time, flummoxed me as well.  I think it will work great with simple things, like incrementing a list, unless it goes too with respect to the number of items, I guess that 2^14, is a boundary with respect to the number of items (16384) by the way, -since that was the old 'limit' with respect to the number of items. Most of the times, I operate on lists with far lesser elements than this, so the overhead has been neglectible. But I too, will think twice, and time when I use the repeat n times.

Comment: @css: no and no. Look, you're speculating blindly on obscure internal implementation details in closed third-party software which you cannot see and cannot change. It's just a fact that the AppleScript interpreter is a bag of crap, but as users there's no point wasting hours/days/months of our lives figuring out exactly why, because there's absolutely nothing we can do about it anyway. It's Apple's toy, not ours. All we can do is live with it or go elsewhere; use the right tool for the job, and all that.

Comment: Consider Python or Ruby for general scripting; while they have their own sets of faults, they are at least well supported and not quite as horribly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, here's the equivalent in Python (which took me a week to get into coming from AppleScript, and I'm a slow learner):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from time import time

def ranger3(n):
    outlist = []
    i = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        outlist.append(i)
        i += 1
    return outlist

def ranger4(n):
    outlist = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        outlist.append(i)
    return outlist

n = 10000000 # 10 million

t = time()
ranger3(n) 
print(time()-t) # 2.2633600235

t = time()
ranger4(n)
print(time()-t) # 1.52647018433
```

Needless to say, both are `O(n)` as you'd expect, in addition to being one or two magnitudes faster than AS - and Python is considered slow compared to most mainstream languages. Just to show how pointless it is obssessing over "performance-optimizing" AppleScript, when every other language leaves it in the dust straight out of the box.

Comment: I'm very appreciative of the time you've taken to answer, give a counter example in py, and for your airing of your thoughts. And I agree with the no point wasting time on it philosophy :) I asked originally since I'm extremely amateur in scripting and was wondering if there was something plain and simple I had overlooked. That said, I don't feel like I can tick this off as answered. And completely understand that I may receive no answer here. Cheers

Comment: P.s. Just saw another answer of yours that mentioned the pypi AppleScript module. Might check that out next :)

Comment: "wondering if there was something plain and simple I had overlooked" -- A fine instinct to culture (wish more "professional programmers" did). But no, AppleScript really is this cranky. Partly it's because it was written to run on 30MHz 68K Macs, back in an age where churning a few hundred items would be considered serious work, and partly because 90s Apple effectively pulled the plug on ongoing development after AS 1.1, so the original devs never had a chance to really polish and optimize it. But all that's a story [for another time](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2006/ashopl.pdf)… :)

Comment: BTW, if you're on 10.10+, you can also call from Python into AS via the [PyObjC and AppleScriptObjC bridges](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html), avoiding the need for third-party modules.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following timer loops on the AS ranger code supplied above:

```
set minIter to 0
set maxIter to 200000
set incIter to 50000

repeat with iters from minIter to maxIter by incIter
    set timeStart to (time of (current date))
    ranger1(iters)
    log (" ranger1(" & iters & ") took seconds:" & (time of (current date)) - timeStart) & " seconds "
end repeat

repeat with iters from minIter to maxIter by incIter
    set timeStart to (time of (current date))
    ranger2(iters)
    log (" ranger2(" & iters & ") took seconds:" & (time of (current date)) - timeStart) & " seconds "
end repeat
```

with these results:

```
(* ranger1(0) took seconds:0 seconds *)
(* ranger1(50000) took seconds:1 seconds *)
(* ranger1(100000) took seconds:3 seconds *)
(* ranger1(150000) took seconds:8 seconds *)
(* ranger1(200000) took seconds:13 seconds *)

(* ranger2(0) took seconds:0 seconds *)
(* ranger2(50000) took seconds:74 seconds *)
(* ranger2(100000) took seconds:262 seconds *)
(* ranger2(150000) took seconds:471 seconds *)
(* ranger2(200000) took seconds:734 seconds *)
```

Certainly ranger1 is (relatively) faster, but definitely not linear, and ranger2 is downright glacial.